# Matlab invalid expression error

Tags: matlab, sign

```
while  B(i,j,k) ~= 0
{ C = C + B(i,j,k);
  i++;
  j++;
  k++;
   }
end
```

i am trying to add a mXnX3 matrix in double to get the sum of (i,i,i) elements but the above declaration gives a matlab error. and i can't seem to correct it. help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This most likely errors, because it is not correct Matlab syntax. Have you read [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/bqr_2pl.html)?

To solve this with a loop, you'd write:

```
C = 0;
for i=1:size(B,1)
   C = C + B(i,i,i);
end
```

To do it in the "Matlab"-way, you'd write

```
nn = size(B,1);
C = sum(B(1:(nn^2+n+1):end));
```

Note: all of the above assumes that B is nxnxn.

If you want to get the sum of *all* elements, you can simply write

```
C = sum(B(:));
```

If you really want to do a triple loop, you write

```
C = 0;
[nI,nJ,nK]=size(B);
for i=1:nI
  for j=1:nJ
    for k=1:nK
       C = C + B(i,j,k);
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: But this is not the sum of the _(i, i, i)_ elements... you just need one loop instead of three.

Comment: @EitanT: The OP is actually rather bizarre, since it doesn't make a lot of sense to add the *(i,i,i)* elements in a mxnx3 array. Anyway, I've fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`i++` is not valid Matlab.  Neither are braces `{}`.

Comment: However, i++ and the like will work under octave. Avoid using if you collaborate with Matlab users.